# googlecode : how to not publish public?

Tags: svn, google-code

I am looking for a free SVN hosting. GoogleCode seems perfect.
Trouble is I have some projects I cannot make open source : is it possible to use the SVN hosting on googleCode and not share them publicaly ?
If not, does someone know an alternative for SVN hosting that does not make it public ?

regards

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible to use the SVN hosting on googleCode and not share them publicaly?

No, it's not. GoogleCode hosts only open projects.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146505/can-someone-recommend-a-reliable-cvs-or-svn-hosting-service) question for SVN hosting providers.

Answer (score 1):

I use and highly recommend [unFuddle.com](http://unfuddle.com)